# ¿Por qué recibo el error "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Intento obtener el índice de un DataFrame, en una de cuyas columnas se encuentra un valor determinado, ejecutando el siguiente script.

```
df = pdr.DataReader("TEF.MC",'yahoo',"2016-1-1","2020-6-23") 
# Cotización media, máxima y mínima  en el período       
cotiz_max = df[["Close"]].max()
cotiz_min = df[["Close"]].min() 
fecha_cotiz_max = df[df['Close']==cotiz_max].index.item()
fecha_cotiz_min = df[df['Close']==cotiz_min].index.item()
```

Me devuelve el error:

> Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

El error parece indicar que la comparación es incorrecta ya que comparamos una serie con un número. ¿Es esta interpretación correcta? Agradeceré sugerencias para conseguir el resultado que pretendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el script que muestro a continuación sustituyo el df `df[["Close"]]` por la lista `df["Close"]`, con lo que el error desaparece

```
df = pdr.DataReader("TEF.MC",'yahoo',"2016-1-1","2020-6-23") 
# Cotización media, máxima y mínima  en el período       
cotiz_max = df["Close"].max()
cotiz_min = df["Close"].min() 
fecha_cotiz_max = df[df['Close']==cotiz_max].index.item()
fecha_cotiz_min = df[df['Close']==cotiz_min].index.item()

fecha_cotiz_min
```